# Volley JSON request doesn't give me response

Tags: android, android-volley

My SearchActivity.java looks like that:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                String query = editText.getText().toString();
                doMySearch(query);
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
}
public void doMySearch(String query) {
    System.out.println("print if doMySearch was opened");
    System.out.println(query);
    List<Show> subscribedShowsList = new ArrayList<Show>();
    String url = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=";
    String final_url = url + query;
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, final_url, (String)null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    System.out.println("print if we got to onResponse");
                    String resss = response.toString();
                    System.out.println(resss);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });

    System.out.println("this is request" + request);
}
}
```

And the console output is:

```
05-04 19:46:39.054 29615-29615/com.example.user.test I/System.out: print if     doMySearch was opened
05-04 19:46:39.054 29615-29615/com.example.user.test I/System.out: girls
05-04 19:46:39.054 29615-29615/com.example.user.test I/System.out: this is   request[ ] http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls 0xfc1517a8 NORMAL null
```

The URL is correct but as you can see onResponse didn't even run. I have tried both JSONArrayRequest and JSONObjectRequest and they (don't) work the same. I have no idea what can be wrong here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `RequestQueue` to fire a Volley request. All you did was create an anonymous class, which does not execute the `onResponse` when you create it.

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(...);
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
queue.add(request);
```